# Диски внутри раздела?

Tags: linux

В порядке обучения надо создать на диске раздел. На диске уже два раздела с системой. Однако, во втором как-то странно определяются еще два "диска". Систему ставил автоустановщиком, до этого две системы ставил сам разделяя диск.

[image: Команда lsblk]

[image: Команда fdisk -l]

Comment: Снимание на type lvm - это LVM http://xgu.ru/wiki/LVM

Comment: У вас уже есть разделы на весь диск, чтобы создать ещё один, необходимо добавить вначале диск, сделать раздел, потом включить его в LVM, если хочется. Или переустановить систему с ручным разбиением по разделам.

Comment: Под "добавить диск" вы имеете в виду добавить физический, например SDD? А есть способ удалить LVM, чтобы содержимое перенеслось на физ. раздел sda2? + вопрос, как понимаю - для деления диска с данными, надо эти данные перенести в его начало, а потом можно выделить еще раздел?